# How can I figure out if a command is piped into another command?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Using a bash function that dumps some information about itself to stderr and then calls `cat` to form a pipeline, how can I tell which stage in the pipeline called which other stage?

One solution is to provide each stage a name like, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and then when I look at the output I know that `a > b > c > d`. But suppose I don't want to name the stages. Is there a way I can look at the file descriptors of the stages and see that one stage's `stdout` is another stage's `stdin` so I know the former is piping into the latter? If so, how do I identify the shared pipe? I tried `lsof` but I don't see how I can establish the chain.

For example,

```
    printf '%s\n' main "$(lsof -p $$ | grep dev)" > /dev/stderr

    pipe() {
        printf '%s %s:%s %s\n' $1 $BASHPID $BASH_SUBSHELL $$ > /dev/stderr
        printf '%s\n' $1 "$(lsof -p $$ | grep dev)" > /dev/stderr
        cat
    }

    echo
    echo hi | pipe a | pipe b | pipe c | pipe d
```

Produces

```
main
bash    51147 Setup    0u   CHR               16,2  0t476770                3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    51147 Setup    1u   CHR               16,2  0t476770                3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    51147 Setup    2u   CHR               16,2  0t476770                3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    51147 Setup   26u   CHR               15,0  0t214349                 579 /dev/ptmx
bash    51147 Setup   27u   CHR               15,1 0t1206500                 579 /dev/ptmx

a 51176:1 51147
d 51147:0 51147
b 51177:1 51147
c 51179:1 51147
b
bash    51147 Setup    1u   CHR               16,2  0t477304                3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    51147 Setup    2u   CHR               16,2  0t477304                3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    51147 Setup   26u   CHR               15,0  0t214349                 579 /dev/ptmx
bash    51147 Setup   27u   CHR               15,1 0t1206500                 579 /dev/ptmx
bash    51147 Setup  254u   CHR               16,2  0t477304                3717 /dev/ttys002
d
bash    51147 Setup    1u   CHR               16,2  0t477304                3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    51147 Setup    2u   CHR               16,2  0t477304                3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    51147 Setup   26u   CHR               15,0  0t214349                 579 /dev/ptmx
bash    51147 Setup   27u   CHR               15,1 0t1206500                 579 /dev/ptmx
bash    51147 Setup  254u   CHR               16,2  0t477304                3717 /dev/ttys002
a
bash    51147 Setup    1u   CHR               16,2  0t477304                3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    51147 Setup    2u   CHR               16,2  0t477304                3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    51147 Setup   26u   CHR               15,0  0t214349                 579 /dev/ptmx
bash    51147 Setup   27u   CHR               15,1 0t1206500                 579 /dev/ptmx
bash    51147 Setup  254u   CHR               16,2  0t477304                3717 /dev/ttys002
c
bash    51147 Setup    1u   CHR               16,2  0t478702                3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    51147 Setup    2u   CHR               16,2  0t478702                3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    51147 Setup   26u   CHR               15,0  0t214349                 579 /dev/ptmx
bash    51147 Setup   27u   CHR               15,1 0t1206500                 579 /dev/ptmx
bash    51147 Setup  254u   CHR               16,2  0t478702                3717 /dev/ttys002
hi
```

But I don't see an identifier of `stdout` in `a` being the `stdin` for `b`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The pipes are anonymous (contrary to named pipes) because they are created with the [`pipe(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) command. However, they of course have an internal ID which is displayed by `lsof` (and which you can see in `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd`).

> But I don't see an identifier of stdout in `a` being the stdin for `b`.

This is because your are not `lsof`-ing the right process. `$$` expands to your script PID, not to the PID of the sub-shells created by the piped command. You must use `$BASHPID` instead.

Modify your function thusly:

```
pipe() {
    local pid=$BASHPID
    printf '%s %s:%s %s\n' "$1" "$pid" "$BASH_SUBSHELL" $$ > /dev/stderr
    printf '%s\n' "$1" "$(lsof -a -p "$pid" -d 0,1)" > /dev/stderr
    cat
}
```

You will now get something like:

```
COMMAND  PID  USER    FD  TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
bash    1290  xhienne 0r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 180254229 pipe
bash    1290  xhienne 1w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 180254230 pipe
```

... where the node number is the internal ID of the pipe. You will then be able to notice that pipe #12345678 connects stdout of `a` to stdin of `b`, and so on.