# Why does `stdin` get re-assigned in a trap?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Why does `stdin` get re-assigned in a trap? For example,

```
    my_trap() {
        lsof -a -p "$BASHPID" -d 0,1,2
    }
    lsof -a -p "$BASHPID" -d 0,1,2
    trap my_trap ERR
    echo hi | grep foo
```

Outputs

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bash    63384 Setup    0u   CHR   16,2 0t1112831 3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    63384 Setup    1u   CHR   16,2 0t1112831 3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    63384 Setup    2u   CHR   16,2 0t1112831 3717 /dev/ttys002
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bash    63384 Setup    0   PIPE 0xde72f1c4316180fd     16384      
bash    63384 Setup    1u   CHR               16,2 0t1113091 3717 /dev/ttys002
bash    63384 Setup    2u   CHR               16,2 0t1113091 3717 /dev/ttys002
```

I see that `stdin` got re-assigned to a pipe `0xde72f1c4316180fd`. What happened? What is that pipe? Can I see what the node id was of the original `stdin` pipe?

---

The reason I'm interesting in the `stdin` and `stdout` pipes in traps is so I when I dump a stack from inside my trap I can also dump the `stdin` and `stdout` node ids. In this way if I have a pipeline that fails and each stage triggers a trap and dumps a stack, then I can figure out for a given stack what other stack it is consuming and to what other stack it is producing by following the `stdin` and `stdout` chain. I cannot build this chain if the `stdin` pipe is re-assigned.

Comment: It's likely the stdin of `grep`. Though I can't reproduce here with `bash` 5.0.17. What's your version?

Comment: GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0)

Comment: Yep, that's what it is.

Comment: I'm also not able to reproduce. Closest I get is using `shopt -s lastpipe` upon where I get a FIFO. And the trap is not triggered for each fail, only for last.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This is not what I would expect. The exit value of grep is supposed to be evaluated in the context of the parent (the script) once the grep process has died, and where stdin is not redirected. Christopher: are you really piping to `grep`? Or are you piping to a custom bash function (like in [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/650496/203203)), which executes grep, while the `errtrace` Bash option is enabled? Please check you can reproduce the issue with the example you give.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I'm piping to `grep` and not a bash function named `grep`.